# What is the fastest way to XOR two integers in C#?

Tags: c#, xor

I need to XOR one integer `a` against array of integers `q` (max of 100,000). i.e. if i am looping, I will

a XOR q[0]

a XOR q[1]

.....

a XOR q[100000]

(100,000 times)

I will have a series of such `a` to be XORed.

I am writing a console application which will be pass the required input.

I am using the built-in C# `^` operator to do the XOR operation. Is there any other way?

Would converting the integer to a byte array and then XORing each bit and figuring out the end result be a good idea?

Input (don't keep the spaces between the two lines)

1

15 8

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

10 6 10

1023 7 7

33 5 8

182 5 10

181 1 13

5 10 15

99 8 9

33 10 14

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XOR
{
    class Solution
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<TestCase> testCases = ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            CalculationManager calculationManager = new CalculationManager();

            foreach (var testCase in testCases)
            {
                var ints = testCase.Queries.AsParallel().Select(query => calculationManager.Calculate(query, testCase.SequenceOfIntegers)).ToList();
                ints.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static List<TestCase> ReadLine()
        {
            int noOfTestCases = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var testCases = new List<TestCase>();

            for (int i = 0; i < noOfTestCases; i++)
            {
                string firstLine = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] firstLineSplit = firstLine.Split(' ');
                int N = Convert.ToInt32(firstLineSplit[0]);
                int Q = Convert.ToInt32(firstLineSplit[1]);

                var testCase = new TestCase
                                   {
                                       Queries = new List<Query>(),
                                       SequenceOfIntegers = ReadLineAndGetSequenceOfIntegers()
                                   };

                for (int j = 0; j < Q; j++)
                {
                    var buildQuery = ReadLineAndBuildQuery();
                    testCase.Queries.Add(buildQuery);
                }

                testCases.Add(testCase);
            }

            return testCases;
        }

        private static List<int> ReadLineAndGetSequenceOfIntegers()
        {
            string secondLine = Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> sequenceOfIntegers = secondLine.Split(' ').ToArray().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
            return sequenceOfIntegers;
        }

        private static Query ReadLineAndBuildQuery()
        {
            var query = Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> queryIntegers = query.Split(' ').ToArray().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
            Query buildQuery = ReadLineAndBuildQuery(queryIntegers[0], queryIntegers[1], queryIntegers[2]);
            return buildQuery;
        }

        private static Query ReadLineAndBuildQuery(int a, int p, int q)
        {
            return new Query { a = a, p = p, q = q };
        }


    }

    class CalculationManager
    {
        public int Calculate(Query query, List<int> sequenceOfIntegers)
        {
            var possibleIntegersToCalculate = FindPossibleIntegersToCalculate(sequenceOfIntegers, query.p, query.q);
            int maxXorValue = possibleIntegersToCalculate.AsParallel().Max(x => x ^ query.a);
            return maxXorValue;
        }

        private IEnumerable<int> FindPossibleIntegersToCalculate(List<int> sequenceOfIntegers, int p, int q)
        {
            return sequenceOfIntegers.GetRange(p - 1, (q - p) + 1).Distinct().ToArray();
        }
    }

    class TestCase
    {
        public List<int> SequenceOfIntegers { get; set; }
        public List<Query> Queries { get; set; }
    }

    class Query
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int p { get; set; }
        public int q { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is going to be faster than the built-in operator.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? There might be a faster way depending on that

Comment: You trying to do an "encryption" function which this?

Comment: C# has built-in array bounds checking, doesn't it? That will slow the thing right down. You need to write it in assembly language, or at the very least C or C++.

Comment: @TonyK not true: the JIT can eliminate bounds checks on classic vector "for" loops, or alternatively: use `unsafe` code and avoid the bounds check in the first place.

Comment: Why not posting your full code to give us better opportunities for speeding it up the algorithmic way?

Comment: i am trying to solve one interview street question, the result is correct but its not able to finish in timely fashion

Answer (score 16):

Using the `^` bit-wise xor operator is the fastest way to xor integers.

The operation is translated to a single atomic processor operation.

As you can see in the disassembly:

```
        int i = 4;
00000029  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],4 
        i ^= 3;
00000030  xor         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],3
```

So if you wish to make your code run faster, you should change the algorithm / approach (as suggested by Marc Gravell), not the xor method.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I'd even try (if there was reason to think the int approach was too slow) would be to use `unsafe` code to treat each `int[]` as a `long*`, and use 64-bit arithmetic (again, using `^`) instead of 32, half the iterations, and a bit less indirection. IIRC that is pretty much what I did for some web-socket code (applying web-socket masks for client-to-server messages is a bulk XOR). You'd need to be careful for the last few bytes, obviously.

Comment: Marc, you know that there is a problem referencing your name with '@'? I suspect it is because of the special character in your nickname.

Comment: There was a small bug in the code I've posted. Here it is now, fixed: http://pastebin.com/iXmTHS51 and by the way, I've tested speeds for this method vs unsafe with int* method, and the long generally takes 65% the time that the int does. So +1 for thinking about it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to xor more elements called a (as you said) against the array you can speed this up the following way:

```
int x = q[0]
for(int i = 1; i < q.Length; i++)
   x ^= q[i]

a1 ^= x
a2 ^= x
...
```

EDIT:
    Sorry, than basically the other way around

```
int x = a1 ^ a2 ^ ... an
for(int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
     q[i] ^= x
```

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question. Pay attention to details.

Comment: Still doesn't solve. `x` is a simple mask. It is given. And anyway, you wouldn't expect him to hardcode `a1 ^ a2 ^ ... an`, right?! What YOU have implemented, assuming the first line is actually implemented with a loop to perform that logic, xors each element with the xor of all elements.

Comment: And even if you fix your algorithm, it STILL doesn't solve the OP's question, because he already had that solution. He was looking for a faster way than a simple loop.

Comment: Hardcoding only if there are a few one ;). If there are n elements of a, and q has a length of 100000 my algorithm needs n + 100000 iterations, while the one he discribed needs n * 100000

Comment: "Assuming the first line is actually implemented with a loop to perform that logic, xors each element with the xor of all elements." Xoring an element with all elements is the same thing as xor an element with the "xoring" of all elements

Comment: What you are misunderstanding here is that the OP wanted to xor a list of elements with a single int (`a`). `for (i:0...n) { list[i] ^= mask; }` or `mask ^= list[i]` for that matter (depends which you want to xor) - that is the logic needed here, where `mask` is a given number, such as `41623`.

Answer (score 0):

XOR is a fast operation so your application will be limited by the rate you can generate the integers.

If you just xor them as they become available the xor time will be neglectable regardless of method.

e.g. if you read the integers from a text file. The disk io + parse time will be several magnitudes bigger than the xor time. The operating system will also use `read-ahead` which in practice means that it fetches the next batch of integers while you process the current batch. This means that parsing + xor adds no extra time to the overall processing time except for the last batch.